# how do you get drag and drop reordering to work in the new ui-grid?

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid, angular-ui-grid

I'm using the new new Angular ui-grid and can't get drag and drop reordering of rows working. I've used

```
enableRowReordering: true
```

in my gridOptions but that appears to do nothing. I can't find anything more in the documents as they just say "just set enableRowReordering to true". Do I need to define my own row template and add something more to each row?

Comment: Try it in Chrome. That's the only browser where I got column reordering working.

Comment: That is what I use. I think I'm just going to try ui-sortable.

Comment: As of this moment drag and drop of ROWS is not supported. But I believe they are working on it, see: https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/1359